# Font Awesome handshake icon did n't work

Tags: font-awesome

I had tried to use handshake icons but it doesn't work, below included us the code which I have tried:

```
<i class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i>
```

Please help me

Comment: You need to include font-awesome.min.css in your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Your code in w3 school tryit editor

It is link for that https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_intro.asp

I think that You are not include the css for font-awesome so include that 'font-awesome.min.css'

[image]

This is the sample screen from try it editor

Comment: now this working properly, i think i had used old version of font -awesome

Answer (score 0):

You need add the CSS files and the font files to make it work. Here is the documentation: http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem to add handshake icon

```
 <span class="fa-stack">
     <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
 </span>
```

First time, it was not shown ever, but after updating the font-awesome **fonts**, and **css** to version 4.7, it works fine. Try to update your local versions of font-awesome **fonts** and **css** with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which works with FontAwesome 6+ in React, that makes it easy to combine icon packs such as the free and pro ones:

1. Add the FontAwesome dependencies to your project:

   ```bash
   npm install --save \
     @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core \
     @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons \
     @fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons \
     @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons \
     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
   ```
2. Declare all FA icons you would like to use in the root of your app:

   ```js
   import { library as fontAwesomeLibrary } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
   import {
     faPlugCircleMinus,
     faPlugCirclePlus,
     faSchool,
     faUsers,
   } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

   fontAwesomeLibrary.add(
     faPlugCircleMinus,
     faPlugCirclePlus,
     faSchool,
     faUsers,
   );
   ```
3. Use a shorthand syntax to display the icons in the relevant components, such as:

   ```js
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
   ...
   const element = (
     <FontAwesomeIcon icon='school' />
   );
   ```

Alternatively, you could also import the individual icons whenever needed. The downside of this approach is that you would have to remember which pack each icon comes from every time you add one to a component:

```js
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faSchool } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
...
const element = (
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSchool} />
)
```